# Get permalink to latest post in category

Tags: categories

I need to get the permalink to the latest post in just one category. That link then needs to be placed into a button. The button is rendered within a function in a custom front-page.php template.

I have this so far but it is not working with various permutations and no errors are showing up:

```
$latest_post = get_post( array( 'cat' => 3, 'posts_per_page' => 1) );
if( $latest_post ) {
    echo '<a href= "' . get_permalink( $latest_post->ID ) . '">Learn More Now</a>';
}
```

Can anyone help show me where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you are using here, `get_post()` does not accept query arguments. So you have to use `get_posts()`. Try this:

```
$latest_post = get_posts( array( 'cat' => 3, 'posts_per_page' => 1) );
if( !empty( $latest_post ) ) {
    echo '<a href= "' . get_permalink( $latest_post[0] ) . '">Learn More Now</a>';
}
```

Comment: arrrggh, for want of an "s"! Thank you @Sohan, it's exactly what I needed and works perfectly.